# How to enable Time Zone support for ASP.NET Core API?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, datetimeoffset

I've got a mobile app and a Web application that consumes an ASP.NET Core 3.x WEB API that uses SQL Server as it's datastore. The client applications can be in different Time Zones.

The dilemma I'm facing is filtering records with a date range.

For instance, I've got a table called `'PaymentTransaction'` that consists of a column `'TransactionDateTime'` that is of type `DateTimeOffset`.

Entity object:

```
[Table("PaymentTransaction")]
public class PaymentTransaction 
{
    public DateTimeOffset TransactionDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

API endpoint for creating the records: **PaymentRequestDto content excluded for brevity**

```
[HttpPost, Route("Create")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Required] PaymentRequestDto)
{
    await _context.PayoutTransactions.AddAsync(new PaymentTransaction()
    {
        TransactionDateTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
    });

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();    
    return Ok();
}
```

API endpoint for filtering the records:

```
[HttpGet, Route("GetRangeSample/{startDateTime}/{endDateTime}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetRangeSample([Required] DateTimeOffset startDateTime, [Required] DateTimeOffset endDateTime)
{
    var result = await _context.PaymentTransactions.Where(x => x.TransactionDateTime >= date && x.TransactionDateTime <= date).ToListAsync();
    return Ok(result);
}
```

JavaScript Client requesting filtered records;

```
var startDate = new Date();
var endDate = new Date();
endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 7)

$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "http://localhost:55724/api/GetRangeSample",
    data:{
        startDateTime: startDate,
        endDateTime: endDate
    },
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(error)
    {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

If I'm to filter records for a given date range, let's say `02-21-2022` to `02-28-2022`. some records are not returned.

What am I doing wrong? How do you normally go about saving a DateTimeOffset and retrieving records based on a date filter?

Comment: `some records are not returned` is it resulting from the different time zone? I noticed that when you stored the create time stamp, you used `UtcNow`, but in js code you didn't turn the `startDate` to UTC time.

Comment: @TinyWang, Yes, when querying for records from different time zones, some records aren't returned as expected. Actually I was just trying something so that's why I had set the `transaction date` to `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow`. What would be the setup ideally? Would you save the DateTimeOffset in UTC and expect an UTC DateTimeOffset as well from the client when querying, or something else entirely?

Comment: I didn't have such scenario in my experience but in my opinion, if I have a client which may running all over the world, I will also make all the time stamp uniformed and when I need to filter by time stamp for users in different time zone, I will get their time zone first and then modify the querying time in js then send the time stamp to the backend.

Comment: @TinyWang - That's unnecessary.  UTC already is "universal".  SQL Server will adjust all `datetimeoffset` queries to UTC anyway.  Storing `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow` is correct and appropriate.

Comment: @nadz - In your query, you're showing a variable `date` that is undefined.  Did you mean to be using the method parameters? It would also help if you showed some data.  Keep in mind that with your current approach, you are using the browser's local time zone when you decided to add 7 days.  If you're just missing data on the edges, the data very well may be outside of that local day.  If you wanted to query based on the "UTC day" or on the day in some other time zone, there are approaches to handle that.  Please clarify.

Comment: Additionally, when you call `new Date()` in javascript, that's not the *start* of the day, but rather it's "now".  You can do `.setHours(0,0,0,0)` to adjust to the start of the day in the local time zone.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint yes the last reply is what I mean, adjust the time user chooing in the js according to local time zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming you mean to have the user select entire days in *their* time zone, the issue is in the way you've created the start and end dates in your JavaScript code.  Keep in mind that a JavaScript `Date` object represents a point in time (*not* a whole date), and that `new Date()` gives the point in time that is *now*.

Thus, you should probably create your start and end dates like this instead, so they are inclusive of the entire day rather than just the  remainder of the day after the time ran the code.

```js
var startDate = new Date();   // get the current "now"
startDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);  // adjust to the start of the local day
var endDate = new Date(startDate);      // copy to another instance
endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 7); // advance 7 days
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. It turned out to be a problem with the datetime parameters sent from the Client. I ended up using Day.Js and it works as expected.
Also I had to change DateTimeOffset.UtcNow; to DateTimeOffset.Now when saving the records.

Comment: The `Now` vs `UtcNow` shouldn't matter, as any query comparing `datetimeoffset` in SQL Server will normalize the values to UTC.  Indexes are also built purely in UTC.  It would only matter for display, to preserve the original offset - or if you are doing something else with the local time from that offset.  Do also keep in mind that `DateTimeOffset.Now` will use the *server's* time zone, not the client's.  Thus it's not usually warranted.